# Unable to talk in SMP chat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, ubuntu

Whenever I enter any server on Minecraft, if I press <kbd>T</kbd> and write later on I can't send that message to the chat. I've already tried removing /bin folder and letting the game download it again, but that didn't work.

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: My os is Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Is the letter T the letter in the controls config for chat? And if you are using the ENTER on the numpad, it'll not work you need to press the "big" ENTER button.

Comment: Yes, it's the chat key. I've tried both, but neither worked

Comment: @gumbo as a test why don't you download the server jar and run it on your local machine and then open minecraft and connect to 'localhost' and see if you can send a message. You will also be able to check the server.log for any errors.

Comment: Unable to write too, and no errors on server.log

Comment: As another test, why don't you re-download the client? IIRC I once had  to re-download it due to a broken update from a too-old version.

Answer (score 4):

If the server is running mods, it's possible that new players aren't given the ability to publicly chat until they've "proven" themselves.  (Though it does seem odd.)  Check the server's web page, if it has one, or try contacting the server admins out-of-game to check whether this is the case.

If you're allowed, you can also post the server's address and port here and I (and probably others) would be happy to report whether we have the same problem on it.  :-)

Comment: Thanks, the server direction is `server.minasapatridas.com` (just paste it). I'll try contacting the mods, though.

Comment: Maybe you could give me a server in which I should be able to write without problems, to test it

Comment: I was indeed able to chat on that server, though there seemed to be significant lag between when I hit `Enter` and when my message appeared and the Information NPC was very spammy so it was sometimes hard to see what I'd written.  I did successfully chat with one of the other players, though, so it was definitely working.  Looks like permissions aren't your problem.  :-/

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is go to options-Chat settings- and make sure that chat is on "shown"

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem it was to do with my keyboard mapping in Ubuntu, not with Minecraft itself. Whilst minecraft only accepts "return" to send chat messages for some reason my laptops return key was mapped to "kp_enter" - which meant it functioned correctly for everything else, but not minecraft.

I used this [guide on remapping keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys) and now it works fine.

Comment: A good solution to see if this is necessary would be to try a different USB keyboard, and compare the output `xev` when you press the keyboard enter and when you press your enter keys.